# Brenda-web AWS rendering - need advice

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rendering, blender

I'm trying to setup a render job with brenda-web. I've had them increase the max allowed to 10. But, so far I've only had the error:
`MaxSpotInstanceCountExceeded: Max spot instance count exceeded`

I'm also not sure if the AMI Presets that it offers are valid currently.  I can't find them in the AMI marketplace.
blender 2.69 ami-0529086c 
blender 2.77 ami-837567e9
blender 2.78 ami-380bd82e

Need some advice how to fix the max instance error. thanks!

Comment: From [aws help](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-spot-limits.html) - `If you terminate your Spot instance but do not cancel the request, the request counts against this limit until Amazon EC2 detects the termination and closes the request.`, using AMI's that have been deleted might cause the failure. I haven't used brenda-web but think it is based off [brenda](https://github.com/robksawyer/brenda) if you want to set it up from scratch. You may be better off looking at [flamenco](https://www.flamenco.io/) which is currently developed and used by the blender institute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake was that I was not queuing any tasks after filling int the template. Therefore; I was requesting instances without any work to do. So they immediately shutdown with a 'Request by user shutdown.'